# How to check substring in shell script bash?

Tags: linux, bash

Actually the string is new.tar.gz I want to check this file is tar package or not ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `file` command to inspect it.

```
$ file new.tar.gz
new.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, last modified: Tue Sep 26 16:50:00 2017, from Unix
```

To inspect the contents of the compressed file, you'll have to extract it, then run file on that:

```
$ gunzip -k new.tar.gz; file new.tar
new.tar: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically, a `tar` archive file may be called *anything*.  The name of a file does not decide the format or contents of the file in Unix.

However, if we restrict the question to determining whether a filename in the variable `$filename` ether ends with the string `.tar` or contains the string `.tar.`, or not:

```
case $filename in
    *.tar|*.tar.*) echo 'possibly a tar file' ;;
esac
```

The above allows for both `.tar` at the end of a name or `.tar` followed by another extension.

Or, in `bash` (the above works in any `sh` shell, including `bash`):

```
if [[ $filename =~ \.tar$  ]] ||
   [[ $filename =~ \.tar\. ]]; then
    echo 'possibly a tar file'
fi
```

or,

```
if [[ $filename == *.tar   ]] ||
   [[ $filename == *.tar.* ]]; then
    echo 'possibly a tar file'
fi
```

---

If you have a file with a long list of filenames, then the following will tell you which *lines in that file* ends with the string `.tar` or contains the string `.tar.`:

```
grep -E '\.tar$|\.tar\.' file.list
```

The `-E` flag tells `grep` to treat the given pattern as an extended regular expression (to handle `|`).

Alternatively,

```
grep -e '\.tar$' -e '\.tar\.' file.list
```

---

To list the *final* extensions of every file in a long list (stored in `file.list`):

```
sed 's/.*\.//' file.list
```

The `sed` expression `s/.*\.//` will remove everything on each line up to and including the final dot.

Comment: You can also use pattern matching in `bash`, which is often a little cleaner than the corresponding regular expression. `if [[ $filename = *.tar ]] || [[ $filename = *.tar.* ]]`. (With extended pattern support enabled, `[[ $filename = *.tar?(.*) ]]`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks. Personally, I prefer `case ... esac` for pattern mating. More portable. Added some of your stuff.