# Match wildcarded string in case statement using sh shell

Tags: shell, wildcards, string, case

I'm having trouble matching a wilcarded string in the `sh` shell. The code is part of a `configure.ac` so it usually gets the lamest shell available. I can't count on the Bash shell.

The code first executes:

```
LDNAME=`basename "$LD"`
```

And I sometimes get a string like `ld -m x86_64` or `ld -m elf64lppc`, but I want just `ld` as a friendly display name.

I then perform a small fixup according to [How to check substring in shell script bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/394583/56041), [Substring check in IF condition in shell script](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/221365-substring-check-if-condition-shell-script.html) and [if/else comparison with wildcard](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/142791-if-else-comparison-wildcard.html) using a `case` statement:

```
case "$LDNAME" in
    "ld -m*") LDNAME=ld
    ;;
esac
```

The string fails to match and I get the original string back. I've also tried `ld -m *` (without quotes) and a few other variations with the same result.

How do I match a wilcarded string in case statement using `sh` shell?

---

This works but it is not very extensible:

```
if test "$LDNAME" = "ld -m elf_x86_64"; then
   LDNAME=ld
fi
if test "$LDNAME" = "ld -m elf64lppc"; then
   LDNAME=ld
fi
```

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
LDNAME="ld -m blah"
case "$LDNAME" in "ld -m"*) echo foo;; esac
```

You need to leave the wildcard `*` unquoted, otherwise it's taken as a literal character.

But really, if all you want is to remove the `-m` and anything after it, you could just use `LDNAME=${LDNAME%% -m*}`.

```
LDNAME="ld -m blah"
LDNAME=${LDNAME%% -m*}
echo ":$LDNAME:"
```

gives `:ld:`.